# How to Handle Database Connection Error Using Java code?

Tags: java

I am connecting to a DB2 server using the following code:

```
try {
     Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
     cnfe.printStackTrace();
}

try {
     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://IP:port/db name", "username", "password");
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
     sqle.printStackTrace();
}
```

If the connection is not established, what is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle the situation"? If you can't connect, and your app relies on a connection, presenting an error message to the user sounds like the only thing you can do. (After optional retries, possibly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking whether you should try to re-connect or not - you most probably don't want to implement that logic yourself, take some connection pooling library like [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0) or [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/).